# Burn installer facing error .Net 45 0x80091007-The hash value is not correct

Tags: .net, frameworks, wix, bootstrapper, burn

I am using Burn installer to install msi and .net framework. But when I try to install .exe it fails with error.

.Net 45 0x80091007-The hash value is not correct. 
I have downloaded the .net exe from [Link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/confirmation.aspx?id=30653)
I got the hashcode using tool from  [fciv tool](http://download.microsoft.com/download/c/f/4/cf454ae0-a4bb-4123-8333-a1b6737712f7/windows-kb841290-x86-enu.exe)

What I am missing in below scenario.

```
<Chain>
      <ExePackage
        Id= "Net45"
        Name = "dotNetFx45_Full_setup.exe"
        Cache= "no"
        Compressed= "no"
        PerMachine= "yes"
        Permanent= "yes"
        Vital= "yes"
        DownloadUrl="http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/confirmation.aspx?id=30653"
        DetectCondition="(Net4FullVersion = &quot;4.5.50709&quot;) AND (NOT VersionNT64 OR (Net4x64FullVersion = &quot;4.5.50709&quot;))">
        <RemotePayload
          ProductName="Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5"
          Description="Net45"
          Size="984000"
          Hash="9E8253F0A993E53B4809DBD74B335227"
          Version="4.5.50709.17929"/>
      </ExePackage>
 <MsiPackage
        Id="Installer"
        SourceFile="$(var.Installer.TargetPath)"
        Compressed="yes"
        Vital="yes"
        Permanent="no"
        DisplayInternalUI="yes"
        Visible="yes">
        <MsiProperty Name="INSTALLLOCATION" Value="[InstallFolder]" />
      </MsiPackage>

      <RollbackBoundary />
    </Chain>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size is wrong, you can look at the WiX toolset source code: https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/ext/NetFxExtension/wixlib/NetFx4.5.wxs.  I would just copy that file into your project and make your modifications there.

Comment: I have used ExePackage section for .Net framework section 4.5, and its working fine.
Is it necessary/good to include everything from file??

Comment: @KeshavdasM It doesn't hurt anything if you include everything from the file, but feel free to delete what you don't need.